# How do I fix an Error in Palindrome program in Java?

Tags: java, string, recursion, boolean, palindrome

I keep getting an error on my palindrome program. The code goes like this:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome_r(String word){
    int beginning = 0;
    int end = word.length() - 1;

    if(word.charAt(beginning) == word.charAt(end)){
        return (isPalindrome_r(word.substring(1, word.length() - 1)));
    }
    else if (word.charAt(beginning) != word.charAt(end)){
        return false;
    }

    return false;
}

public static boolean isPalindrome_nr(String word){
    int beginning = 0;
    int end = word.length() - 1;

    boolean pd = true;

    for (int i = end; i>=0; i--){
        if(word.charAt(i) != word.charAt(end-i)){
            pd = false;
        }
    }

    return pd;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("Is the string a palindrome or not? ");
    String test = "test";
    String test_2 = "level";
    String test_3 = "application";
    System.out.println("Answer: " + isPalindrome_r(test));
    System.out.println("Answer: " + isPalindrome_r(test_2));
    System.out.println("Answer: " + isPalindrome_r(test_3));
    System.out.println("Answer: " + isPalindrome_nr(test));
    System.out.println("Answer: " + isPalindrome_nr(test_2));
    System.out.println("Answer: " + isPalindrome_nr(test_3));

}
```

The error output in regards to the test_2 on the recursive version goes like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
at assignment1cs.recursion.isPalindrome_r(recursion.java:12)
at assignment1cs.recursion.isPalindrome_r(recursion.java:12)
at assignment1cs.recursion.isPalindrome_r(recursion.java:12)
at assignment1cs.recursion.main(recursion.java:80)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You have no stopping condition. You should terminate the recursion if the remaining String length < 4;

If the length is 1, just return true.
If the length is 2 or 3, return true if first = last.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (it's important not forgetting the case when s.length() < 2) :

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
        int length = s.length();
        if (s.isEmpty() || length == 1) 
            return true;
        return s.charAt(0) != s.charAt(length - 1) ? false : isPalindroma(s.substring(1,length - 1));
    }
```

Comment: It is not good to give the answer away. This site is not for people who cannot do their homework. clearly your compact way will make the teacher go nuts lol

Comment: No problem, you have a point. However, he was close, that's why I answered.

Comment: you could put some ideas or hints to help the OP closer to the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

After some rounds of execution, your substring generated by `word.substring(1, word.length() - 1)` might be of length 0.

Hence, on the next iteration of your recursion:
`int end = word.length() - 1;` will be -1
and `word.charAt(beginning) == word.charAt(end)` would be `word.charAt(0) == word.charAt(-1)` hence resulting in the run time error you saw.